# Adding logical or gate in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I want static text to be printed only if any one or more of the textField has a value.

I have tried with following code but goal is not achieved. Following code is not working when all the textField is empty except the last one (`HAEMATOLOGY_BASOPHILS`). I think with following approach once boolean false is returned rest of the logical or gate is not getting executed.

```xml
<printWhenExpression>< ![CDATA[((!$F{HAEMATOLOGY_NEUTROPHILS}.isEmpty()) || (!$F{HAEMATOLOGY_EOSINOPHILS}.isEmpty()) || (!$F{HAEMATOLOGY_BASOPHILS}.isEmpty()))]]></printWhenExpression>

    <text><![CDATA[Differential Count]]></text>
```

PS : My english is not good. So, sorry for the grammatical error.

Comment: Did you try to add check for null?

Comment: Yep...i have tried with it.I have written the code in the aboe post.

HAEMATOLOGY_NEUTROPHILS}.isEmpty()